# VSCode icon is existed, but won't run after click on and code" command not found

Tags: nvidia, software-installation, firefox, visual-studio-code

Just installed miniconda, reinstalled NVIDIA Driver and manually set up the environment for TensorFlow-GPU. After that, some of my applications had gone: my default text editor (command: "gedit"), VSCode (command: "code"), as well as my firefox browser (command: "firefox") cannot be found. I still have the VSCode icon on the all application menu but it is unusable.

[VSCode icon is shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WrlR.jpg)

["code" command not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tDvv.png)

I have searched my problem on Google but it seems that there hasn't been a problem like mine. I have fixed the problem by reinstalling all the missing applications. My newly installed Firefox has all the bookmark and Onetab sessions I saved.
I wonder if anyone has ever experienced a problem like mine and has diagnosed why it happened.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? You are sure you did not do anything else? Run update and or upgrade?

Comment: My Ubuntu version is 20.04. I did run "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade" and got "All packages are up to date...0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded."

Comment: "manually set up the environment for TensorFlow-GPU." Unsure what you did there, but that may have caused these system wide problems. Obviously diagnosis is difficult if we do not know exactly what you have done with the system. Maybe the problem is changing your PATH. Applications that are not found are also not shown in the Application overview.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Some commands I ran could have changed my PATH. My description above may be vague, so I attached bash history for the environment setting up here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZM_JaR82YSd-iTwQuoIAXjGNCYj6msZrCo60mjpQFHE/edit?usp=sharing